# How to change value of global var when it is being used as a parameter in a function? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

I want to be able to change the value of a global variable when it is being used by a function as a parameter.

My javascript:

```
function playAudio(audioFile, canPlay) {

    if (canPlay < 2 && audioFile.paused) {
        
        canPlay = canPlay + 1;
        audioFile.play();

    } else {

        if (canPlay >= 2) {
            alert("This audio has already been played twice.");
        } else {
            alert("Please wait for the audio to finish playing.");
        };

    };

};

const   btnPitch01        = document.getElementById("btnPitch01");
const   audioFilePitch01  = new Audio("../aud/Pitch01.wav");
var     canPlayPitch01    = 0;

btnPitch01.addEventListener("click", function() {

    playAudio(audioFilePitch01, canPlayPitch01);

});
```

My HTML:

```
<body>

    <button id="btnPitch01">Play Pitch01</button>
    <button id="btnPitch02">Play Pitch02</button>

    <script src="js/js-master.js"></script>

</body>
```

My scenario:

I'm building a Musical Aptitude Test for personal use that won't be hosted online. There are going to be hundreds of buttons each corresponding to their own audio files. Each audio file may only be played twice and no more than that. Buttons may not be pressed while their corresponding audio files are already playing.

All of that was working completely fine, until I optimised the function to use parameters. I know this would be good to avoid copy-pasting the same function hundreds of times, but it has broken the solution I used to prevent the audio from being played more than once. The "canPlayPitch01" variable, when it is being used as a parameter, no longer gets incremented, and therefore makes the [if (canPlay < 2)] useless.

How would I go about solving this? Even if it is bad coding practise, I would prefer to keep using the method I'm currently using, because I think it is a very logical one.

I'm a beginner and know very little, so please forgive any mistakes or poor coding practises. I welcome corrections and tips.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can use the elements dataset attribute to save the unique infomation against the button itself: in your addEventListener, use this.dataset.pitchNum or similar value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset here you can read/write data for the element. this can allow you to record the number of plays allowed, and the number used. you can then have the button change state based on those values too

Comment: there are better approaches that were covered somehow by someone else.. anyway to strictly address the question itself, you need the scope to address the given variable. There's a scenario that would fit with the question.. if you declared a variable with no const/let/var it would belong to the `window` scope. So in that case, if you are inside a scope with a variable having the same name but still want to address the _global_ one, you should do `window.variablename`

Comment: @ThisGuy that sounds very promising; thank you! I'll just have to watch more tutorials, haha.

Comment: @DiegoD This also looks like a very easy solution; I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, since variables are passed by value, not by reference. You should return the new value, and the caller should assign it to the variable.

```
function playAudio(audioFile, canPlay) {
  if (canPlay < 2 && audioFile.paused) {
    canPlay = canPlay + 1;
    audioFile.play();
  } else {
    if (canPlay >= 2) {
      alert("This audio has already been played twice.");
    } else {
      alert("Please wait for the audio to finish playing.");
    };
  };
  return canPlay;
};

const btnPitch01 = document.getElementById("btnPitch01");
const audioFilePitch01 = new Audio("../aud/Pitch01.wav");
var canPlayPitch01 = 0;

btnPitch01.addEventListener("click", function() {

  canPlayPitch01 = playAudio(audioFilePitch01, canPlayPitch01);

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry to ask, but I'm not sure how to use the returned variable. If you could explain further, I would be thankful. You did give me a different idea, though. Perhaps I could do the [+1] in the "anonymous function" (I think that's what it's called?)

Comment: I showed how to use it. You assign it back to the variable that was used as the argument, with `canPlayPitch01 =`

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement of the data will fix the stated problem and probably have quite a few side benefits elsewhere in the code.

Your data looks like this:

```
const btnPitch01 = document.getElementById("btnPitch01");
const audioFilePitch01 = new Audio("../aud/Pitch01.wav");
var canPlayPitch01 = 0;

// and, judging by the naming used, there's probably more like this:
const btnPitch02 = document.getElementById("btnPitch02");
const audioFilePitch02 = new Audio("../aud/Pitch02.wav");
var canPlayPitch02 = 0;

// and so on
```

Now consider that global data looking like this:

```
const model = {
  btnPitch01: {
    canPlay: 0,
    el: document.getElementById("btnPitch01"),
    audioFile: new Audio("../aud/Pitch01.wav")
  },
  btnPitch02: { /* and so on */ }
}
```

Your event listener(s) can say:

```
btnPitch01.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // notice how (if this is all that's done here) we can shrink this even further later
  playAudio(event);
});
```

And your `playAudio` function can have a side-effect on the data:

```
function playAudio(event) {
    // here's how we get from the button to the model item
    const item = model[event.target.id];
    if (item.canPlay < 2 && item.audioFile.paused) {
        item.canPlay++;
        item.audioFile.play();
    } else {
        if (item.canPlay >= 2) {
            alert("This audio has already been played twice.");
        } else {
            alert("Please wait for the audio to finish playing.");
        };
    };
};
```

**Side note:** the `model` can probably be built in code...

```
// you can automate this even more using String padStart() on 1,2,3...
const baseIds = [ '01', '02', ... ];
const model = Object.fromEntries(
  baseIds.map(baseId => {
    const id = `btnPitch${baseId}`;
    const value = {
      canPlay: 0,
      el: document.getElementById(id),
      audioFile: new Audio(`../aud/Pitch${baseId}.wav`)
    }
    return [id, value];
  })
); 

// you can build the event listeners in a loop, too
// (or in the loop above)
Object.values(model).forEach(value => {
  value.el.addEventListener("click", playAudio)
})
```

Comment: That's incredible. Thank you so much for your expertise. I was frightened of how complicated it would be if I did optimise the code like you did, but you made it look very achievable. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

below is an example of the function.

```js
btnPitch01.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if ( this.dataset.numberOfPlays >= this.dataset.allowedNumberOfPlays ) return;
    playAudio(audioFilePitch01, canPlayPitch01);
    this.dataset.numberOfPlays++;
});
```

you would want to select all of your buttons and assign this to them after your html is loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
const listOfButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('pitchButton');
listOfButtons.forEach( item => {
item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if ( this.dataset.numberOfPlays >= this.dataset.allowedNumberOfPlays ) return;
    playAudio("audioFilePitch" + this.id);
    this.dataset.numberOfPlays++;
    });
```

Comment: This seems like a very neat and concise solution; thank you! All of the suggestions I've received are great; it's just a matter of me experimenting and seeing which one is the easiest for me to get working.